# Android Smack 4.1.1 File Transfering, ERROR Could not establish socket

Tags: android, xmpp, openfire, smack, asmack

I am trying to send files over my android app with smack library 4.1.1, though i am having some errors to do so. The thing is that i don't know why it just sends the files to a device but after that it doesn't let me to send to others and others can't send to others either, for example the first time i opened a listener with one device, that device could and can still send files just to one device (the first that it sent) but the one that receives can not, the file seems to arrive but with 0 data or maybe it doesn't arrive and just when arrives something causes error i am not sure but after a while i don't know if the connection or something breaks and i can send files with any other device but not with another, just one. and the others gets this error:

I also test it with spark and i can receive files perfectly from spark even though when i send a file to spark it shows error on spark also.

Logs

```
    06-28 17:57:54.430    3394-3758/com.example.example D/SMACK﹕ SENT (0): <iq to='example.com' id='36V0P-179' type='get'><query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items'></query></iq>
    06-28 17:57:54.463    3394-3759/com.example.example D/SMACK﹕ RECV (0): <iq type="result" id="36V0P-179" from="example.com" to="+10000000000@example.com/Example"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items"><item jid="pubsub.example.com" name="Publish-Subscribe service"/><item jid="proxy.example.com" name="Socks 5 Bytestreams Proxy"/><item jid="conference.example.com" name="Public Chatrooms"/></query></iq>
    06-28 17:57:54.464    3394-3758/com.example.example D/SMACK﹕ SENT (0): <iq to='pubsub.example.com' id='36V0P-181' type='get'><query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info'></query></iq>
    06-28 17:57:54.485    3394-3759/com.example.example D/SMACK﹕ RECV (0): <iq type="result" id="36V0P-181" from="pubsub.example.com" to="+10000000000@example.com/Example"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info"><identity category="pubsub" name="Publish-Subscribe service" type="service"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#access-open"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#collections"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#config-node"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#create-and-configure"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#create-nodes"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#delete-nodes"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#get-pending"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#instant-nodes"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#item-ids"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#meta-data"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#modify-affiliations"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#manage-subscriptions"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#multi-subscribe"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#outcast-affiliation"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#persistent-items"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#presence-notifications"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#publish"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#publisher-affiliation"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#purge-nodes"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#retract-items"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#retrieve-affiliations"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#retrieve-default"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#retrieve-items"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#retrieve-subscriptions"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#subscribe"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#subscription-options"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info"/></query></iq>
    06-28 17:57:54.486    3394-3758/com.example.example D/SMACK﹕ SENT (0): <iq to='proxy.example.com' id='36V0P-183' type='get'><query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info'></query></iq>
    06-28 17:57:54.501    3394-3759/com.example.example D/SMACK﹕ RECV (0): <iq type="result" id="36V0P-183" from="proxy.example.com" to="+10000000000@example.com/Example"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info"><identity category="proxy" name="SOCKS5 Bytestreams Service" type="bytestreams"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info"/></query></iq>
    06-28 17:57:54.502    3394-3758/com.example.example D/SMACK﹕ SENT (0): <iq to='conference.example.com' id='36V0P-185' type='get'><query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info'></query></iq>
    06-28 17:57:54.518    3394-3759/com.example.example D/SMACK﹕ RECV (0): <iq type="result" id="36V0P-185" from="conference.example.com" to="+10000000000@example.com/Example"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info"><identity category="conference" name="Public Chatrooms" type="text"/><identity category="directory" name="Public Chatroom Search" type="chatroom"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/muc"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items"/><feature var="jabber:iq:search"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm"/></query></iq>
    06-28 17:57:54.523    3394-3758/com.example.example D/SMACK﹕ SENT (0): <iq to='proxy.example.com' id='36V0P-187' type='get'><query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams'/></iq>
    06-28 17:57:54.537    3394-3759/com.example.example D/SMACK﹕ RECV (0): <iq type="result" id="36V0P-187" from="proxy.example.com" to="+10000000000@example.com/Example"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams"><streamhost jid="proxy.example.com" host="198.105.244.228" port="7777"/></query></iq>
    06-28 17:57:54.539    3394-3758/com.example.example D/SMACK﹕ SENT (0): <iq to='+11111111111@example.com/Example' id='36V0P-189' type='set'><query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams' sid='jsi_3989032673038256169' mode='tcp'><streamhost jid='+10000000000@example.com/Example' host='fe80::5054:ff:fe12:3456%eth0' port='7777'/><streamhost jid='+10000000000@example.com/Example' host='10.0.2.15' port='7777'/><streamhost jid='proxy.example.com' host='198.105.244.228' port='7777'/></query></iq>
    06-28 17:57:59.564    3394-3759/com.example.example D/SMACK﹕ RECV (0): <iq type="get" id="843-84" from="example.com" to="+10000000000@example.com/Example"><ping xmlns="urn:xmpp:ping"/></iq>
    06-28 17:57:59.566    3394-3758/com.example.example D/SMACK﹕ SENT (0): <iq to='example.com' id='843-84' type='result'></iq>
    06-28 17:58:01.304    3394-3759/com.example.example D/SMACK﹕ RECV (0): <iq to="+10000000000@example.com/Example" id="36V0P-189" type="error" from="+11111111111@example.com/Example"><error type="cancel"><item-not-found xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/><text xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas" xml:lang="en">Could not establish socket with any provided host</text></error></iq>
    06-28 17:58:01.308    3394-3758/com.example.example D/SMACK﹕ SENT (0): <iq to='+11111111111@example.com/Example' id='36V0P-193' type='set'><open xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb' block-size='4096' sid='jsi_3989032673038256169' stanza='iq'/></iq>
```

it is really wierd, i dont really know what i am doing wrong. look at my code

SEND FILE:

```
public static void sendFile(String Username, String filePathAndName, AbstractXMPPConnection connection){
        Log.e("FILENAMEing file", "to " + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + Example.DB_FOLDER + File.separator + "myText.jpg");
        Log.e("FILENAMEing file", "to " + Username);

        FileTransferManager manager = FileTransferManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
        OutgoingFileTransfer transfer = manager.createOutgoingFileTransfer(Username + Example.DOMAIN + "/" + Example.APP_NAME);
        try {
            transfer.sendFile(new File(filePathAndName), "This is a Test!");
        } catch (SmackException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

RECEIVING FILES:

public static void setFileTransferListener(AbstractXMPPConnection connection){

```
    FileTransferManager manager = FileTransferManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
    // Create the listener
    manager.addFileTransferListener(new FileTransferListener() {
        @Override
        public void fileTransferRequest(FileTransferRequest request) {
            IncomingFileTransfer transfer = request.accept();
            try {
                File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()  + File.separator + Example.DB_FOLDER + File.separator + "myFile22.jpg");
                transfer.recieveFile(file);
            } catch (SmackException | IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I would love to read any answer or hint. I am stuck on this for 2 days D: i really need help :/.

The port is forwarded ofcures like i said it works with one device or the first deviced that open a listener first i think.

Comment: I haven't used smack for file transferring, but what you describe sounds like a one-to-one/one-to-many/many-to-many problem, a good place to start would be to check for support on those, it might explain some of the weird behavior you're seeing

Comment: I dont know where to check it , even though i reboot the server it just works for some devices only and then  i cant use it again for other devices :/ @TommySM, the same problem stars again and over again. :c i dont know how to fix it, i have tried many things but nothing

Answer (score 3):

I hope this helps anyone, the api works fine even though we need to change some properties in our openfire server:

```
1.  xmpp.proxy.enabled – true 
2.  xmpp.proxy.port – 7777 (7777 is the default but could be another)
3.  xmpp.proxy.externalip – (host or ip)
```

At the time it is working very well, need to make more tests though, I am wrong please someone provide any other info to fix this.

Comment: in server where this code have to write? @Kobbycoder

Comment: Im sorry for the delayed answer. You need to go to Server Manager > System Properties > add new Property

Comment: ALSO, remember to reboot the server after making this change :-)